# Finding dublets and variations in mssql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a whole bunch of data. In that table there is a row, with not unique ids, so there can be dublets of them - I have found them by doing this query:

```
SELECT theid FROM thetable
GROUP BY theid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

In the table there is also columns like street1,street2,city1,city2

In the list of rows from the first query where I found dublets, in those I need to check if street1 is different from street2 and city1 from city2, in any of the dublets of the given id from the first query - makes sense?

So lets say we have two rows with the same ids - in those i need to check if street1 is different from street1 in all rows with the specific id

Any tips, pointers on how to do this, I am getting blind starring at this problem, and cant seem to find the right query for that.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Can you provide us with sample data and results?

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE will help:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT theID,
         Street1,
         Street2,
         Street3,
         City,
         State,
         Zip,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY theID ORDER BY theID)
  FROM Table
  -- add joins if necessary
)
SELECT oldestID = c1.theID,
       oldestStreet1 = c1.Street1,
       newestStreet1 = c2.Street1,
       newestID = c2.theID
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
```

You could also add a case statement to display matches vs. non-matches. This will help to manually identify typos (1337 Test St. vs 1337 Test Street):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT theID,
         Street1,
         Street2,
         Street3,
         City,
         State,
         Zip,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY theID ORDER BY theID)
  FROM Table
  -- add joins if necessary
)
SELECT oldestID = c1.theID,
       oldestStreet1 = CASE WHEN c1.Street1 = c2.Street1 THEN 'Match' ELSE c1.Street1 END,
       newestStreet1 = CASE WHEN c1.Street1 = c2.Street1 THEn 'Match' ELSE c2.Street1 END,
       newestID = c2.theID
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
```

Or you could return just the items that do not match by adding it to your `INNER JOIN` clause:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT theID,
         Street1,
         Street2,
         Street3,
         City,
         State,
         Zip,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY theID ORDER BY theID)
  FROM Table
  -- add joins if necessary
)
SELECT oldestID = c1.theID,
       oldestStreet1 = c1.Street1,
       newestStreet1 = c2.Street1,
       newestID = c2.theID
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 AND c1.Street1 <> c2.Street1 -- add as many of these as you need.
```

Keep in mind these are exact matches. You could implement static-fuzzy logic `LEFT(Zip, 5)` to match only on the first 5 digits of Zip Code (in case some have a zip + 4 and some don't.)

Comment: Hey - that wont work, will it? As if I have 19 dublets of one id, i need to make 19 joins?

Comment: Depending on what key identifier you use. If you have duplicates on `theID` 19 times, then you could just use the CTE to display them all, rather than just the first two. Or, if possible, append a unique identifier into the CTE. Or use a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

you can also analyse like this,

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT theID,
         Street1,
         Street2,
         Street3,
         City,
         State,
         Zip,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY theID ORDER BY theID)
  FROM Table
  -- add joins if necessary
)
,
CTE1 as
(
 select *,ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(PARTITION BY theID,Street1,Street2,City,State,Zip 
oRDER BY theID) rn2 from cte where rn>2
)
select * from cte1
```